rmarkdown hide an entire section
I am making a beamer presentation and I want to hide a slide unless the user click on a link.  For example, in this code:
---
title: "teste"
output: beamer_presentation
date: "2024-10-28"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.

## Slide content

- Summary

## Slide summary

```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
summary(cars)
```

I want that "Slide summary" does not appear in the presentation, but when the user click on "Summary" in the "Slide content" he will be directed to the "Slide summary".
